# Copy arabic data from old SQL server database

Tags: sql-server

I have existing data in SQL Server 2008 that has Arabic data in varchar column that I need to copy to SQL Server 2014. When I query the data I see text like èíë¢ïëë¢é Is there a solution. Can I do it through C# application.

I have tried INSERT using Arabic Collation on the source, bcp utility to export using codepage 1256.

Comment: are the collation on both databases the same?

Comment: SQL Server has no issues with Arabic, provided you *do* use Unicode ie nvarchar. Otherwise you have to ensure that source, target *and* bcp use the same encoding. And the current and *future* applications, web sites and *web browsers* that use your data. That's why people use nvarchar instead. Why are you using BCP? Why not backup/restore or linke one server to another and use a simple INSERT? Make sure the target is `nvarchar` though. Even if you need to use bcp make sure you export the data as Unicode.

Comment: You can use the -N option in [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) to export/import the data  in Unicode (UTF16). This will avoid errors even if source and target are ASCII instead of Unicode. Check [UTF-8 encoding support for the BCP utility and BULK INSERT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sq). It shows how to use UTF8. It isn't needed though when migrating from one SQL Server to another

Comment: The source column is varchar. Simple Insert produces result like è©ï«¢ïŸë  ©ëŸ©§. This is what I see when I query the source table. So the destination (is nvarchar) also shows è©ï«¢ïŸë  ©ëŸ©§. So tried with bcp if it could help.